# How to fill an array with function inline

Tags: arrays, .net-core

Are exists in .Net 5 something like `Array.Fill(myArray, 1)` but with function.

I mean `Array.Fill(myArray, myRandom.Next(10))` or another function. Actually, this code is possible but it counts function once and fills the whole array with the result.

My goal can be achieved with `myArray = Array.ConvertAll(Of Integer, Integer)(myArray, Function(i) myRandom.Next(10))` but it looks a little strange and also wastes CPU time by redundant array constructor calls.

Of course, it can be simply performed with a loop, but some inline better complies with the style of the current project.

Samples are provided in VB.Net but of course, the question is related to .Net not to any particular programing language.

Comment: Hey how about writing an extension method called Fill?

Comment: @Shane Not a bad idea, I'm already done it, but just interested to know, maybe I wrote redundant code, as I understood - not.